# Vectors and Planes with parametric equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors, analytic-geometry, 3d

Any help would be appreciated!

Find a parametric equation of a line $L$ that is obtained as the intersection of the planes $P$ and $Q$ with scalar equations $$P: x+2y+3z=4$$ and $$Q: x-3y+z=1$$

Related to this is the question:

Give a parametric equation of a line $M$ contained in $Q$ and orthogonal to $L$.

Note: This is from a Calculus course so any advice involving linear algebra may not be of much help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal to the plane P is $\vec p=\vec i+ 2\vec j+ 3\vec k$
Normal to plane Q is $\vec q=\vec i-3 \vec j+\vec k$
The direction vector for the line of intersection is $\vec L=\vec p \times \vec q= 11 \vec i+2 \vec j-5 \vec k.$
For a common point in two plane, let $z=t$
$$x+2y=4-3t~ \& x-3y=1-t \implies y=(3-2t)/5, x=(14-11t)/5$$ Let $t=-1$, the common point is $(5,1,-1)$, the Eq. og line is
$$\frac{x-5}{11}=\frac{y-1}{2}=\frac{z+1}{-5}=s.$$
The parametric Eq. of line is
$$x=11s+5, y=2s+1, z=-5s-1, s \in \Re$$

**EDIT**  $\vec M. \vec L=0$ and also $\vec M. \vec p=0$
$$\implies \vec M= \vec L \times \vec p=2(8\vec i-19 \vec j + 10\vec k).$$ One can again use the point $(5,1,-1)$ to write the equation of M as
$$\frac{x-5}{8}=\frac{y-1}{-19}=\frac{z+1}{10}=u, u \in \Re $$

Comment: How can I use this parametric equation of $L$ to find an orthogonal line $M$ in the plane $Q$? I know that $\vec L \cdot \ \vec M = 0$ will prove that they are orthogonal but how to make sure that $M$ is contained in the plane $Q$?

Comment: @Ahson Yousef  you may see my answer again I have added some more stuff.

Comment: @Z Ahmed wouldn't this give the line contained in the plane P?

Comment: Oh! yes but you can do similarly for the line in the plane Q.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is a question from a Calculus course, it boils down to linear algebra, since the whole problem is a system of linear equations. You need to solve the system

$\begin{align*}
x+2y+3z &= 4 \\
x-3y+z &= 1
\end{align*}$

When you solve this, which you can do directly using substitution, you find that

$\begin{align*}
x &= -\frac{11}{5}z + \frac{14}{5} \\
y &= -\frac{2}{5}z + \frac{3}{5} 
\end{align*}$

This is a parametrization of the line you are looking for. If you prefer the vector equation, you could write it as

$$\mathbf{r}(t) = \frac{1}{5}(-11t+14, -2t + 3, t).$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\vec r(t)=\frac{1}{5}(-11t+14,-2t+3,t)$

Comment: Yes, that one slipped. Thank you for noticing! It is now corrected.